# Figuring out camera pitch and roll given RA and DEC of center of image, as well as lat,long of camera and time taken

Tags: coordinate, declination, right-ascension

What I am trying to figure out is how to get the camera pitch and roll, as described in this image [image] (the green yaw line is where the camera sensor is pointing

if given a RA, DEC (of center of image,ie where camera is pointing) LAT, LONG, roll from north celestial pole, az, and TIME

For example:

```
RA = 333.678881
DEC = 62.911565
ROLL_FROM_POLE = 92.904036
TIME = 10/26/22 16:51:05 UTC
LAT = -116.232476
LONG = 32.213847
AZ = 60
```

I feel like all the info is there to do this calculation but I'm having trouble fitting it together

for clarification: yaw would be directly related to azimuth and I already know azimuth so don't need that part., My intuition here says that says I know the location in the sky I'm looking (RA and DEC) as well as time/location/azimuth, I should be able to figure out what the camera/telescope orientation is.

Comment: "Roll from pole" is not a standard term, so it needs clarification.  Also need to know what you want the roll pitch and yaw relative to.  It partly seems like you just want Alt/Az coordinates and the camera rotation relative to the horizon.  Computing Alt/Az from RA/Dec is pretty standard and easy to find references for.

Comment: pitch and roll would be relative to gravity, ie if the camera was totally flat, looking straight up, pitch and roll would be 0,0. Yaw is similar to az here but, as you said that is pretty standard and I already know how to get that.

Comment: If you already know part of the solution, you should edit your question to specify, so other people don't spend their time trying to answer that part.  Alt/Az is relative to gravity, so that's the coordinate system you want for two of the variables.  Since you already know how to do that, you should probably focus your question on specifying what "roll from pole" is, and ask about converting that into Alt/Az coordinates.

Comment: my question sepcifically asked for pitch and roll not yaw, bnut I see ur point. Anyways, I'm not following what alt and az have to do what I'm asking I'm trying to find the pitch and roll of the camera given a RA and DEC (ie, I know where in the sky I'm looking since I also know the time and location). From that, I need to find the orientation of the camera ie, if I had it tilted "forward" 45 degrees relative to looking straight up, the pitch would be 45 degrees

Comment: As it stands, you're not going to get an answer.  Try exolaining what "roll from the pole" means.

Comment: To be honest Im not suree what roll from pole means, I got that description from the python library Im using for this (https://tetra3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_docs.html) which returns all this information from a given image of the starts. It describes the "Roll" returned as "’Roll’: Rotation of image relative to north celestial pole."